# Phonegap 3.5.0 + Android 4.4.2 -- stuck on "Connecting to Device" screen

Tags: android, cordova

I installed phonegap (v. 3.5.0) and tried running the default "Hello World" app on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2. It stays on the "Connecting to Device" screen forever.

When using the Dalvik Debug Monitor, I found the following error:

`06-19 12:15:54.261: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23049): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>` is a line in the index.html file by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into something similar when I was messing with PhoneGap 3.1.  At the time I thought it had something to do with my PhoneGap installation.  The workaround was to find the phonegap.js file and manually copy it into {project}/www folder.

Eventually I switched to using Cordova (which utilizes cordova.js) and I do everything but editing the code from the Command Line Interface (CLI).  I'm using Visual Studio or NotePad++ for editing.

Are you using the CLI to do your build, or are you using the PhoneGap Build service?  My hunch is the Build service would insert it for you automatically, but I haven't tried it so that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue: I followed the phonegap instructions to create a Hello World app, compiled for Android and iOS and just saw "Connecting to Device..." forever in both emulators.

I tried user3704578's proposed solution and manually copied phonegap.js into the {project}/www folder but this did not solve the problem.

What *did* solve the problem was switching from phonegap to cordova.  Following the instructions in [this document](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) and starting over from scratch produced an app that worked in both platforms. Go figure!